# Can an unescaped apostrophe in a literal defined in strings.xml cause my app to crash?

Tags: android

Google's official documentation mentions:

Escaping apostrophes and quotes

If you have an apostrophe or a quote in your string, you must either escape it or enclose the whole string in the other type of enclosing quotes. For example, here are some stings that do and don't work:

```
<string name="good_example">"This'll work"</string>
<string name="good_example_2">This\'ll also work</string>
<string name="bad_example">This doesn't work</string>
<string name="bad_example_2">XML encodings don&apos;t work</string>
```

My question is: Would unescaped quotes cause the application to crash or would it just have no effect and the quotes won't appear in the app UI? Would it crash on specific Android versions? I ask this because if I don't escape this symbol, Eclipse SDK gives me compilation errors but I came across a third-party app code which does not escape these characters, it crashes randomly and I'd like to confirm that this is/ is not one of the possible reasons for the crash.

Comment: Perhaps read the error messages and the stack trace and debug before declaring the crash as 'random'

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I meant that though other users have reported the crash, I'm not able to reproduce it either on the simulator or on my Android device so I'd like to know if this is something that can cause the crash.

Comment: Tip to avoid frustration: I've noticed that it's necessary to clean the project between builds when correcting the XML to one of the good examples shown above.

Answer (score 9):

The "third-party app code" might not be up-to-date. The requirement to escape quotes has been introduced at some point in time last year (don't remember exactly when) by an updated aapt.

The backslash is just a hint for aapt, it is not making its way into the apk file. Thus, I would not expect an app to crash for this specific reason.

Comment: Thank you. That was the confirmation I needed.